# How I get a value from the furthest node from left and right

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have to find a value and the distance between the distant nodes from a bst. I've already made an method which can find the distance between both, but how I can pick a value inside the node?

```
  public int diameter(Node root)
   {
       // base case if tree is empty
       if (root == null)
           return 0;

       // get the height of left and right sub-trees
       int lheight = height(root.left);
       int rheight = height(root.right);

       // get the diameter of left and right sub-trees
       int ldiameter = diameter(root.left);
       int rdiameter = diameter(root.right);

       /* Return max of following three
         1) Diameter of left subtree
         2) Diameter of right subtree
         3) Height of left subtree + height of right subtree + 1
        */
       return Math.max(lheight + rheight + 1,
               Math.max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
   }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "picking a value inside the node"?

Comment: I mean get the element of the node, so after I can manage to choose the variables inside that node.

For example, what I need to do is sorting and calculating from a periodic table on a BST, and for each node I will have an element, but in each element will be more informations like the phase, group, name , etc, and I have to get the more distant nodes and the info of each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a reference to the furthest node; the way it is written, the function only return the distance. Please be aware that I did not compile the snippet so it may need adjustements, but just to give the idea:

```
    class HeightResult {
        int value;
        Node node;
    }
    
    class DiameterResult {
        int value;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        DiameterResult(int value, Node left, Node right) {
            this.value = value;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
    
    public DiameterResult diameter(Node root) {
       // base case if tree is empty
       if (root == null)
           return 0;

       // get the height of left and right sub-trees
       HeightResult lheight = height(root.left);
       HeightResult rheight = height(root.right);

       // get the diameter of left and right sub-trees
       DiameterResult ldiameter = diameter(root.left);
       DiameterResult rdiameter = diameter(root.right);

       /* Return max of following three
         1) Diameter of left subtree
         2) Diameter of right subtree
         3) Height of left subtree + height of right subtree + 1
        */
       
         if (lheight.value + rheight.value + 1 >= Math.max(ldiameter.value, rdiameter.value)) {
            return new DiameterResult(lheight.value + rheight.value + 1, lheight.node, rheight.node);
         } else if (ldiameter.value >= rdiameter.value) {
            return ldiameter
         } else {
            return rdiameter;
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: In the code you provide I can't see where I can reach the element of both nodes from each point of the diameter. Is something escaping from my view?

Comment: DiameterResult contains the value, the left node and the right node, the two points of the diameter